# Problems finding the shortest path on the matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I wrote a part of program but could not find how to continue.This is my homework and ı ve been working on it for ten days and my time is about to expire.
My program requirements:
a) get N as input by keyword.
b) generate random integers between 1 and N*N
c) fill in the matrix with these integer 
I've done this but I couldn t get more.

The more is =>greedy approach
 for example user enter 3 as input.
and program return like matrix

1 2 6

4 8 5

3 9 7

the shortest path is 1,2,6,5,7.
the other example user enter 4 as input and program return matrix like

14 11 6 8

15 3 16 1

10 4  2 5

12 9  7 13

the shortest path can be 14,11,3,4,2,5,13,

and cross steps are not allowed in path.

My code is below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Challenge1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value for the matrix size.");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        int[][] x = randomMatrix(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] randomMatrix(int n) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
        boolean[] trying = new boolean[n * n];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt(n * n) + 1;
                if (trying[matrix[i][j] - 1] == false)
                    trying[matrix[i][j] - 1] = true;

                else {
                    while (trying[matrix[i][j] - 1] == true) {
                        matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt(n * n) + 1;
                    }
                    trying[matrix[i][j] - 1] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do these numbers hold any significance in finding the shortest path? To clarify I have no idea what you mean by `The more is =>Number of neighbor will check and will continue with the smallest.` It's just incomprehensible.

Comment: the program will check Number of neighbors and will continue with the smallest.

Comment: I think the path is meant to start at the left upper corner and finish in the lower right corner; its cost would be the sum of the entries which lie in the path.

Comment: @ZpCikTi I doubt that a greedy aproach will yield a global optimum.

Comment: Oh alright then, the previous example (before edit) just went along the edge on a path which certainly didn't have the smallest cost.

Comment: Yes it is greedy aproach.

Comment: @ZpCikTi Have you read about exhaustive recursive algorithms? The basic idea in this example would be to have a list of previously visited elements of the matrix; then for each visited node (starting from the upper-left corner) you recursively visit the neighbouring nodes which haven't been visited yet. With each visit you update your cost, and when you arrive at the end you compare it to the previously recorded minimal cost. This algorithm exhausts all the possible paths, which is why it's named so.

Comment: No, I have never heard before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some python-ish pseudocode for the solution I've mentioned in the comment. Let `shortestPath` be an initially empty list and `shortestPathCost` be the sum of the weight of the shortest path found yet. Initially its value is `+infinity`. Both are visible globally.

```
 Procedure exhaustiveSearch (currentCost, currentPath, endNode):
      currentNode = currentPath.last
      if currentNode == endNode and currentCost < shortestPathCost:
           shortestPath = currentPath
           shortestPathCost = currentCost
           return

      for each neighbouringNode of currentNode not in currentPath:
           exhaustiveSearch (currentCost + neighbouringNode.cost, 
                             currentPath + neighbouringNode,
                             endNode)
```

That's pretty much it. The parameters are copied by value. If you invoke it as such:

```
 exhaustiveSearch(0, [firstNode], endNode);
```

the `shortestPath` and `shortestPathCost` are going to hold one of the shortest paths in the grid. Obviously the solution is on a bit higher level than `Java` itself, but it should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: I think you add "neighboringNode" twice at the end. EDIT: Never mind, you fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I had changed some of the parameters but not the invocation. Thanks for correction.